# form in a php variable not clickable

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make a delete button so that users can interact with date on my server. However when i can't get my form to be clickable. Everything appears to output as valid html so i'm not really sure why it isn't working

```
function getEvents($date = ''){
//Include db configuration file
include 'dbConfig.php';
$eventListHTML = '';
$date = $date?$date:date("Y-m-d");
//Get events based on the current date
$result = $db->query("SELECT first, last, address1, address2, city, state, zip, phone, AppointmentTime, Notes, ailment, pin, date FROM QueryTable WHERE date = '".$date."' AND status = 1");
if($result->num_rows > 0){
    $eventListHTML = '<h2>Events on '.date("l, d M Y",strtotime($date)).'</h2>';
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $eventListHTML .= ''.$row['date']. ''.$row['AppointmentTime'].' '.$row['first']. ' ' .$row['last']. '' .$row['address1']. ' ' .$row['address2']. '' .$row['city']. '' .$row['state']. '' .$row['zip']. '';
                    $eventListHTML .= '<td>'.$row['Notes']. '</td>';
                    $eventListHTML .= '<td>'.$row['ailment']. '</td>';
                    $eventListHTML .= '<td>'.$row['pin'].'</td>';
                    $eventListHTML .= '<form action="http://localhost/portal/delete.php" method="post"><input type="submit" name="submit"></form>';
    }
}
echo $eventListHTML;
}
```

Everything outputs fine buy when i try to click the button generated by my form it doesnt do anything.

Fred, see below (updated)

[image]

Hey guys if your interested on digging into this issue a small amount here is a link to where it is hosted.

username = demo

pw = demo

its on the calendar tab

http://hubenterprises.com.mx/portal3/

Comment: Check with F12 in a browser, does the form make a post? Also, how does the server know what record to delete? You are not prvoviding that info anywhere int he button. You could also use plain <a href="delete.php?id=123"> tags for this?

Comment: how does your final html looks like?

Comment: putting a php var inside it isnt the problem. When i click the submit button nothing happens. at the moment all i want it to do is go to my delete.php page. I'll post a picture of how my code outputs

Comment: If you're trying to delete a row, there isn't anything in what you posted to do that. Plus, the `delete.php` file could also play a part in all this.

Comment: A: `<form>` cannot be child of `<table>`. @Krunkmaster

Comment: the form when on a page by itself redirects to the delete.php page. So my issue is that the form button isn't clickable

Comment: I'll say it again: A: `<form>` **cannot** be child of `<table>`. I should have just pasted this in the answers area.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I'll try to take it out of the table to see if i can get a better result

Comment: @Krunkmaster ping me back (as I did here) when it does so I'll just post that as the solution here. and you're welcome ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- So i took it out of the table but it still doesn't want to be clicked. I'll post a picture

Comment: @Krunkmaster remove the table stuff and just do a regular `<form>...</form>`.

Comment: @Krunkmaster `<form>` is still child here as per your new screenshot.

Comment: Ok, Ill remove all the table stuff. hold on

Comment: @Krunkmaster plus, if that's your full code, there's a brace too many here `echo $eventListHTML;
}` << and error reporting would have thrown you something about it.

Comment: it's not the full code. Let me update the whole function. I still can't get this thing to click

Comment: So i totally removed the table elements but the thing still is not clickable.

Comment: @Krunkmaster I've made an edit to my answer below. You'll need to base yourself on that. You'll have to reload it.

Comment: I'll give it a shot. Thank you for your time! <3

Comment: @Krunkmaster I noticed that you have some JS at work here `getEvents()` which may also be playing a role here and TBH, JS is not my strong points. If the contributing problem is JS-related, I regret to say that I am not the guy for this and have made a slight edit to my answer in regards to JS at the bottom of my answer. The JS and related tag should have been added to the original question.

Comment: Yea it's some tabs. It didnt effect the front form however. I tossed the project up on my server so you guys can check it out. login credentials are USER - demo PW -demo

Comment: on a side note.. i removed the javascript and it does not appear to have an effect on my problem ><

Comment: @Krunkmaster Viewing your HTML source, reveals 2x `<html>` tags. The one in `</head>
<html>` <<< needs to be removed. You may also want to do `<!DOCTYPE html>` then `<html>` after it in the opening. Your submit btw, appears to be working on that page as I managed to log in given URL you gave us, unless the testing needs to be done in that other page?

Comment: @Krunkmaster your dashboard file also has the same problem with the duplicate `<html>` tags. The "Make Appointment" also appears to have worked, yet I didn't insert anything inside the inputs. I'm using the latest version of Firefox btw. The calendar tab also appear to be working for me.

Comment: the other page does submit correctly. Thats why i thought the issue was the way i was putting a form into a $variable. Let me try what you suggested cause that could def be a problem

Comment: really nice catch on that btw. I feel dumb XD

Comment: @Krunkmaster I made an additional edit to my answer below in regards to those extra `<html>` tags; I believe the question should now be marked as solved. Btw, I revisited the question to see if any other comments were left. It would have been easier to have pinged me ;-) *Cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Hey Fred. I made the changes you mentioned but that has not helped my situation. I have been doing some debugging and i think the problem may be in a jquery ajax call that generates that dates. I'll post the rest of the code on that page along with the code on the corresponding page.

Comment: @Krunkmaster Ok. Well, as I stated earlier, if it is indeed a JS problem, I am not the guy for this. Post your code and maybe someone will pick up on something. Really wishing for a 100% solution on this for you, *cheers*

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Everything you said / suggest is indeed correct. My problem is a special one indeed. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 2):

As I stated in comments, `<form>` **cannot** be child of `<table>`.

Therefore you need to reverse those and place `<form></form>` outside of `<table></table>`.

---

Edit:

```
include 'dbConfig.php';
$eventListHTML = '';
$date = $date?$date:date("Y-m-d");
//Get events based on the current date
$result = $db->query("SELECT first, last, address1, address2, city, state, zip, phone, AppointmentTime, Notes, ailment, pin, date FROM QueryTable WHERE date = '".$date."' AND status = 1");
if($result->num_rows > 0){

    $eventListHTML = '<h2>Events on '.date("l, d M Y",strtotime($date)).'</h2>';

    $eventListHTML .= '<form action="http://localhost/portal/delete.php" method="post">';


    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

        $eventListHTML .= '<table>';
        $eventListHTML .= '<tr><td>'.$row['date']. '</td><td>'.$row['AppointmentTime'].'</td><td> '.$row['first']. '</td><td> ' .$row['last']. '</td><td>' .$row['address1']. '</td><td> ' .$row['address2']. '</td><td> ' .$row['city']. '</td><td>' .$row['state']. '</td><td> ' .$row['zip']. '</td></p>';
        $eventListHTML .= '<td>'.$row['Notes']. '</td>';
        $eventListHTML .= '<td>'.$row['ailment']. '</td>';
        $eventListHTML .= '<td>'.$row['pin'].'</td>';
        $eventListHTML .= '<td><input type="submit" name="submit"></td>';
        $eventListHTML .= '</tr>';  
        $eventListHTML .= '</table>';
    }

        $eventListHTML .= '</form>';

}
echo $eventListHTML;

} // extra brace? Doesn't pair up with what was originally posted.
```

Sidenote: You may have to put some of the elements back outside the loop and/or the form inside the loop.

However, you have a stray `</p>` tag in `$row['zip']. '</td></p>';` <<<

If you wish to have `<form>` be constantly duplicated, then you will need to put it back into the loop.

**Note:** There appears to have some JS used in your code which may be playing a role here. Run it without the JS and as a single form without the table elements.

---

**Additional edit:**

Upon visiting the URL you posted and viewing the HTML source, all of your files that I viewed contained an additional `<html>` tag such as `</head> <html>`; they need to be removed.

Notice the following:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Senior Mobility Care Initiative Lead Portal</title>
<link href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<html>
^^^^^^ Remove those.
```

This is as I stated in comments.

It's also best to use `<!DOCTYPE html><html>` since certain browsers may throw you something about it in HTML source warnings.

If you're using some type of framework that is creating those dynamically, then you need to check and see what is creating the additional `<html>` tag under `</head>`.

Comment: whoever downvoted this, went and serial downvoted me on 3 more answers. The question has been flagged to a moderators.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, when I run into a situation where something is inexplicably non-clickable; the issue is usually a DOM element overlapping the item I am trying to click.

Inspect the DOM and try and find if there is anything overlapping your submit button or link.

Comment: It does not appear to. I posted picture of how the html outputs above

Comment: Is the issue simply that you never get to the else conditional then? As in, you can click the button but the page doesn't take you to the result of the query?

Comment: correct. But the conditional statement does run. Otherwise the <table> wouldn't be generated.

Comment: It looks like your intention here is to delete the row when you click the submit button. However, I do not see that you are posting up an id to designate what is going to be deleted. My guess is your query is just not deleting anything because you didn't post up an id in a hidden field.

Comment: You are correct. But it's not supposed to yet. I'm just trying to make the button clickable XD.

Comment: Ah ok, then I would go back to my original answer. Looks like you're in chrome, I would use inspector's "Select an element in the page to inspect it" feature in the upper left of the panel and then hover over the submit button to confirm that nothing is overlapping it.